# Linear Transformation satisfying polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $V$ have a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear endomorphism $T : V\rightarrow V$ such that $T^4+14T+28=0$. Prove that $4|\dim{V}$ and for $\dim{V}=4$, $T$ is unique up to similarity.

I am unsure how to approach this. I have tried using minimal polynomial divisibility to no avail. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: I assume that $T^4=T\circ T\circ T\circ T$

Comment: Yes sir, you are correct. Exponentiation is composition and addition of 28 is seen as adding 28 times the identity endomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\;x^4+14x+28\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ is irreducible (why?) , so this one is the minimal polynomial of $\;T\;$ over the linear space $\;V_{\Bbb Q}\;$ . But this minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial of $\;T\;$ , which has degree equal to $\;\dim V\;$ ...

Comment: What is $\dim$? I have never seen that before. I’m gonna take a guess, but does it stand for *dimension*? Sorry if I am a bit amateur at this.

Comment: @user477343 Yes. It is a usual notation for dimension in linear algebra and beyond...

Comment: I have just seen questions with for example, *let $A_1, A_2,\ldots A_i$ be dimensions. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^i A_n$ is also a dimension $B$*. The $\dim$ notation makes it easy, so thank u for showing me :)

Comment: How does this answer imply the result? The fact that the characteristic polynomial has a quartic factor implies that the dimension is at least 4, but I don't see how it immediately implies that the dimension is divisible by 4.

Comment: @WillR  From the given info the OP can (or should) deduce the characteristic polynomial is *a power* of the minimal one (why?), and thus the result...It is not *a direct* implication. A little more work is due.